# My Angular project starts with Cannot Get

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-core, iis-express

I am building an Angular project in Visual Studio 2017. I have a Dotnet Core Web API for backend.

When I start both project the Angular   project gives 404 error. Reloading the page makes no change.

When I change and save somthing on any typescript file and reload the page it receives the angular pages.

Is it somthing about IIS? I changed the starting order of but it didnt solve the problem.

This is the aa.module.ts

```
import { PaginationComponent } from './shared/pagination.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { ModelComponent } from './model/model.component';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer/customer.component';
import { VehicleFormComponent } from './vehicle-form/vehicle-form.component';
import { VehicleService } from './services/vehicle.service';
import { VehicleListComponent } from './vehicle-list/vehicle-list.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    ModelComponent,
    CustomerComponent,
    VehicleFormComponent,
    VehicleListComponent,
    PaginationComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      //{ path: '', redirectTo:'vehicles', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
      { path: 'model', component: ModelComponent },
      { path: 'customer', component: CustomerComponent },
      { path: 'vehicles', component: VehicleListComponent },
      { path: 'vehicles/new', component: VehicleFormComponent },
      { path: 'vehicles/:id', component: VehicleFormComponent },
    ], { useHash: true })
  ],
  providers: [VehicleService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Without any more context, I'll go with your server not redirecting all incoming requests to `index.html`. To avoid that, use `{ useHash: true }` when declaring your root routing module

Comment: RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    ], { useHash: true })  ]

Comment: Exactly. Did it solve your issue ?

Comment: No, unfortunatelly

Comment: Then please provide more context to your issue.

Comment: It started after adding a service.

Comment: well if you're not willing to cooperate, I can't help you, I'm sorry. Good luck with your issue, hope you resolve it !